# Simplest way to export (and import) definitions?

Tags: export, list-manipulation

Consider I have this code :

```
f[1]=2
f[1.5]=6
f[3]=4
```

What is the simplest way to save the array f defined on those three numbers in a file ? (in my case, I will have a lot of values, not juste three but the indices of my array will be regularly spaced).

How can I tell in a simple way to mathematica I want to save the full array f ? Am I forced to somehow loop on the indices ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both [`Save[filename,f]`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Save.html) and [`DumpSave[filename,f]`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DumpSave.html) will do. You can read the definitions back with [`Get[filename]`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Get.html).

Comment: the __f is to specify I am talking about the full array f and not the variable f ?

Comment: It only looks like there are underscores because I've made hyperlinks. Just `Save[filename,f]`. By the way, `f` is not an array.